# How can i make this inline

Tags: flutter

I want email and username beside the avatar but i am really confused about this matter cz i am new in flutter.My codes are below:
drawer:

```
Drawer(    
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.amber,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        accountName: Text('Jakir Hossen MIthu', 
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
        ),
        accountEmail: Text('Jakir98@gmail.com', 
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
        ),
        currentAccountPicture: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          child: Image(
            image: NetworkImage("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0b/0e/44/0b0e44587af8a83dcab6892e9376646d.jpg"
            ),
          width: 70,
          height: 70,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Your question is missing information. Try your best to follow the guidelines available here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

That's because `UserAccountsDrawerHeader` seems to have that specific layout. Try using a `DrawerHeader` and create the layout you want by yourself, something like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.amber,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    child: Image(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0b/0e/44/0b0e44587af8a83dcab6892e9376646d.jpg"),
                      width: 70,
                      height: 70,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 16),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Jakir Hossen MIthu',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Jakir98@gmail.com',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```